# can anyone tell my why in bootstrap3 there is an -15px margin for .row and 15px padding for .col-*

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

i fount that in bootstrap3, there is an -15px margin for .row and 15px padding for .col-*.

this seems did nothing, can anyone tell me the secret?

```
.row {
   margin-right: -15px;
   margin-left: -15px;
}
.col-xs-1,
.col-sm-1,
...
.col-md-12,
.col-lg-12 {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Cols have gaps between them. This is simply how they make the first col in a row not have a gap in most compatible way. They could use either this or css first of type selector which older browsers dont support

Comment: wow, so it's just for simply resolve the first col left padding and last col right padding?

Answer (score 0):

`col-` classes have same pixels of padding say `15px` in both side so that you can get `30px` gutter space between each column. If you have a `row` inside a `container` it will give `15px` extra padding between container and row as container has `15px` padding in both left and right side. To avoid this extra space, the cols have `-15px` margin. It will help to get a neat column layout while you nesting rows inside cols.

I hope you understood.